# Docker and Postgresql: Role "username: does not exist

Tags: postgresql, windows, docker, docker-compose, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am running Docker Desktop with WSL backend on Windows 11.
I am trying to create a postgres container in my setup form a compose file as specified below:

```
version: '3'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: pg_test
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: test
      POSTGRES_USER: dummy
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: dummy
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

However on trying to connect to the container I am seeing the following issue:

```
2023-12-30 22:36:13 2023-12-30 17:06:13.657 UTC [33] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "dummy"
2023-12-30 22:36:13 2023-12-30 17:06:13.657 UTC [33] DETAIL:  Role "dummy" does not exist.
```

I have tried switching the ports and killing all processes listening on the port before trying. This issue seems to persist regardless of those attempts. Does anyone know what the issue here is?

Comment: Notice that the user will not be created if data is already present in the mount. So you may want to try deleting the volume `postgres_data`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like default values for above postgres variables are cached in your volume.

Delete your current volumes and re-deploy your compose file.

You can view the current volumes using `docker volume ls` and remove the specific volume using `docker volume rm <vol-name>`